# Parse JSON Array rather than JSON Object

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

any help would be much appreciated...

I am fairly new to android and java. I have previously built an app which parses a JSON array within a JSON Object to a listview. What I need to do in my new app is to parse a JSON array that is not contained in a JSON object and I am having trouble figuring out how to adapt my code.

```
Java Activity:
public class StationListActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {


ListView mainListView;
JSONAdapter mJSONAdapter;



private static final String QUERY_URL = "url.json";
ProgressDialog mDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_station_list);




    // Access the ListView
    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


    // Create a JSONAdapter for the ListView
    mJSONAdapter = new JSONAdapter(this, getLayoutInflater());

    // Set the ListView to use the ArrayAdapter
    mainListView.setAdapter(mJSONAdapter);

    mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mDialog.setMessage("Searching");
    mDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // Create a client to perform networking
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    // Show ProgressDialog to inform user that a task in the background is     occurring
    mDialog.show();




    // Have the client get a JSONArray of data
    // and define how to respond
    client.get(QUERY_URL, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject) {

                    // Dismiss the ProgressDialog
                    mDialog.dismiss();

                    // update the data in your custom method.
                    mJSONAdapter.updateData(jsonObject.optJSONArray("-Here I     would have JSON Object name which contained JSON Array-"));
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable throwable,     JSONObject error) {

                    // Dismiss the ProgressDialog
                    mDialog.dismiss();

                    // Display a "Toast" message
                    // to announce the failure
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network error,     please close app and try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    // Log error message
                    // to help solve any problems
                    Log.e("applog", statusCode + " " +     throwable.getMessage());
                }
            }
    );

}
```

Example JSON:

```
[
    {
    "name": "Silver", 
    "id": 12, 
    "number": 34
    }
]
```

.
.
.

Example JSON I know how to work with:

```
{"title":
    [
        {
        "name": "Silver", 
        "id": 12, 
        "number": 34
        }
    ]
}
```

It may not be the cleanest solution but would it be possible to add some java to assign the retrieved JSON to a JSON object as in my second example?

Comment: So you are used to using a JSON object which key is the name and the value is a JSON array of JSON objects, right? All you have to do is access each JSON object in the json array response you are getting now by iterating over each element in the JSONArray. I can give you an example if necessary

Comment: If you could, that would be great.

Comment: Essentially all that's required is calling new JSONArray(String jsonFile), and then iterating over the array with a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
client.get("https://www.google.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

@Override
public void onSuccess(String response) {
   JSONArray result = new JSONArray(response);
    for(int i = 0; i < result.length(); ++i){
        JSONObject obj = result.getJSONObject(i);
        //do something with obj
    } 
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is what you are looking for, notice I modified the onSuccess method to correspond with a string response.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Am I correct in saying that this will return individual objects from the array in turn? I understand the value of that, the only thing is my code is written to accept in the entire array and there is a JSON adapter which will inflate a listview.

Is there any way to get the array into the format of my second example above?